# Wordpress reports a database error, but repair does nothing

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm running a Wordpress server, pre-configured by Bitnami.

I attempted to restore a backup, but something went wrong. Now I get a `Error establishing a database connection` error when trying to access the site, and a `One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.` when trying to access the site as an admin.

Running a repair results in nothing, with the page saying all the tables are fine.

Everything I've found online related to this error suggests it may be an error with the wp-config.php file, but the database information there seems to be correct (or at least accurate enoguh to allow my to access the tables via the myslq CLI).

Answer (score 0):

First try to install empty WordPress.Then import and restore the database from PHPMyAdmin.

You can use your old WordPress files too. After complete the installation, you only need to upload your image files. You can do that by any FTP client.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a complete reinstall. What about my themes and plugins?

Comment: If you upload wp-content folder, you will get back your themes and plugins.